# Cassandra 2.1.10: Cannot rename Commit log files

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I am a newbie please bear with me if not very clear with the query.

I have been working with cassandra for sometime. But suddenly it has stopped working with the issue being reported as "Error processing commit log during intialization" and that it is "rename of .log file failed".

I have searched for similar reports but could not solve the issue.

I tried the following:
   1. clearing the DataStax Community\data\commitlog folder all but one log file   is always locked with cassandra.
   2. Changed the Windows Defender setting to allow the cassandra folder and not scan the .log files

I am using Datastax Communitity Cassandra version 2.1.10 with Java 1.8 64-bit working on a single node.

Thanking in anticipation
Sujata

The console log:

```
:1.8.0_45]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
INFO  11:32:11 Initializing key cache with capacity of 100 MBs.
INFO  11:32:11 Initializing row cache with capacity of 0 MBs
INFO  11:32:11 Initializing counter cache with capacity of 50 MBs
INFO  11:32:11 Scheduling counter cache save to every 7200 seconds (going to         save all keys).
INFO  11:32:12 Initializing system.sstable_activity
INFO  11:32:16 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax     Community\data\data\system\sstable_activity- 5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e\system-sstable_activity-ka-1299 (1471 bytes)
INFO  11:32:16 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e\system-sstable_activity-ka-1301 (1698 bytes)
INFO  11:32:17 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e\system-sstable_activity-ka-1300 (1560 bytes)
INFO  11:32:17 Initializing system.hints
INFO  11:32:17 Initializing system.compaction_history
INFO  11:32:17 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca\system-compaction_history-ka-938 (343 bytes)
INFO  11:32:17 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca\system-compaction_history-ka-937 (14710 bytes)
INFO  11:32:17 Initializing system.peers
INFO  11:32:17 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\peers-37f71aca7dc2383ba70672528af04d4f\system-peers-ka-1 (30 bytes)
INFO  11:32:17 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\peers-37f71aca7dc2383ba70672528af04d4f\system-peers-ka-2 (30 bytes)
INFO  11:32:17 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\peers-37f71aca7dc2383ba70672528af04d4f\system-peers-ka-3 (30 bytes)
INFO  11:32:17 Initializing system.schema_columnfamilies
INFO  11:32:17 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\schema_columnfamilies-45f5b36024bc3f83a3631034ea4fa697\system-schema_columnfamilies-ka-532 (6166 bytes)
.....
INFO  11:32:23 Initializing OpsCenter.pdps
INFO  11:32:23 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\OpsCenter\pdps-2d611410725d11e58514c92bd1990991\OpsCenter-pdps-ka-234 (13992 bytes)
INFO  11:32:23 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\OpsCenter\pdps-2d611410725d11e58514c92bd1990991\OpsCenter-pdps-ka-233 (13727 bytes)
ERROR 11:32:23 Unable to delete C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377\system-local-ka-476-Data.db (it will be removed on server restart; we'll also retry after GC)
.....
INFO  11:32:24 Initializing people.employees
INFO  11:32:24 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\data\people\employees-ae275410730211e5b8b0c92bd1990991\people- employees-ka-2 (364 bytes)
INFO  11:32:24 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\data\people\employees-ae275410730211e5b8b0c92bd1990991\people- employees-ka-3 (188 bytes)
INFO  11:32:24 Opening C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\data\people\employees-ae275410730211e5b8b0c92bd1990991\people- employees-ka-1 (238 bytes)
INFO  11:32:24 reading saved cache C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\saved_caches\KeyCache-ba.db
INFO  11:32:24 Completed loading (15 ms; 124 keys) KeyCache cache
INFO  11:32:24 Replaying C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\commitlog\CommitLog-4-1456038026082.log
INFO  11:32:24 Replaying C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\commitlog\CommitLog-4-1456038026082.log
INFO  11:32:24 Replaying C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\commitlog\CommitLog-4-1456038026082.log (CL version 4, messaging  version 8)
INFO  11:32:28 Finished reading C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\commitlog\CommitLog-4-1456038026082.log
INFO  11:32:28 Enqueuing flush of compaction_history: 1188 (0%) on-heap, 0  (0%)off-heap
INFO  11:32:28 Enqueuing flush of compactions_in_progress: 1325 (0%) on- heap, 0(0%) off-heap
INFO  11:32:28 Writing Memtable-compaction_history@1259797467(0.231KiB  serialized bytes, 9 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  11:32:28 Enqueuing flush of sstable_activity: 692 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%)  off-heap
INFO  11:32:28 Writing Memtable-compactions_in_progress@165723692(0.154KiB  serialized bytes, 10 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  11:32:28 Completed flushing C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\data\system\compactions_in_progress-55080ab05d9c388690a4acb25fe1f77b\system-compactions_in_progress-tmp-ka-1-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1456054336525, position=1020)
INFO  11:32:28 Completed flushing C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca\system-compaction_history-tmp-ka-939-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1456054336525, position=1020)
INFO  11:32:28 Writing Memtable-sstable_activity@810221833(0.031KiB serialized bytes, 4 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  11:32:28 Completed flushing C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e\system-sstable_activity-tmp-ka-1302-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1456054336525, position=1020)
INFO  11:32:28 Log replay complete, 2 replayed mutations
ERROR 11:32:28 Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.io.IOException: Rename from C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\commitlog\CommitLog-4-1456038026082.log to 1456054336526 failed 
at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:177) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentManager$4.call(CommitLogSegmentManager.java:397) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentManager$4.call(CommitLogSegmentManager.java:394) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentManager$1.runMayThrow(CommitLo gSegmentManager.java:152) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Rename from C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\commitlog\CommitLog-4-1456038026082.log to 1456054336526 failed
at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init> (CommitLogSegment.java:149) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
INFO  11:32:28 Compacting [SSTableReader(path='C:\Program Files    (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\size_estimates    618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86\system-size_estimates-ka-1280-Data.db'),    SSTableReader(path='C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax    Community\data\data\system\size_estimates- 618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86\system-size_estimates-ka-1281-Data.db'),  SSTableReader(path='C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax  Community\data\data\system\size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86\system-size_estimates-ka-1278-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\data\data\system\size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86\system-size_estimates-ka-1279-Data.db')]
```

Comment: The size of each log file is 32 MB. Is this normal or not?

Comment: Also to mention I had started working on Spark after which Cassandra started behaving as above.

Comment: On linux, this is common if you've run sstable* tools (sstable2json, sstablescrub, sstableverify, etc) as an Administrator, as doing so generates a commitlog segment, which will be owned as a different user. I'm not sure if the same holds true for windows, but it seems plausible.

Comment: Thank you Jeff for your inputs. I tried to reinstall the version as I had run out of options.  The installation repair solved the problem without disturbing my data. Though still I am clueless as to what action caused the database initialization to fail